# Get all selected values on change with VueJS 3

Tags: vue.js, onchange, vuejs3, computed-properties

I have these lines inside my component:

```
        <li
          v-for="(c, i) in choice[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]"
          :key="`choice-${choice[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]}-${i}`">
          <input
            @change="changeValue($event, messagesRobot[numMessage].choice)"
            :value="c.id"
            type="checkbox"
            :name="choix[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]"
            :id="`c-${choix[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]}-${i}`">
          <label :for="`c-${choix[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]}-${i}`">
            {{ c.nom }}
          </label>
        </li>
```

As you can see, there are a lot of computed properties. What I would like is to update the model when the user changes the value. The problem is that I can't use something like `:v-model="xxx"`, so I have to capture the `@change` event. I wrote this:

```
function changeValue(e, v) {
  console.log(v);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
}
```

The second line only gives me the last element the user selected or unselected, what I would like is to get ALL the values of the checkboxes, in an array, as it would do if I could use a `v-model`.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this

```
        <li
          v-for="(c, i) in choice[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]"
          :key="`choice-${choice[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]}-${i}`">
          <input
            @change="changeValue($event, messagesRobot[numMessage].choice, i)"
            :value="c.id"
            type="checkbox"
            :name="choix[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]"
            :id="`c-${choix[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]}-${i}`">
          <label :for="`c-${choix[messagesRobot[numMessage].choice]}-${i}`">
            {{ c.nom }}
          </label>
        </li>
```

```
  data() {
    return {
      valuesArray: []
    }
  }
```

```
function changeValue(e, v, index) {
  this.valuesArray[index] = e.target.value;
  console.log(v);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e.target.value));
}
```

then your `valuesArray` would have all the checked values.
Why can't you just use `v-model`?

Comment: Because Vue doesn't seem to accept a `:v-model` with a computed model value inside.

Comment: oh, didn't know that

Comment: Neither did I before trying :D